# Send a notification when the app is closed

Tags: android, notifications

How is it possible to send a notification programmatically, when the App got completely closed?

Example: The User closed the App, also in the Android Taskmanager, and waits. The App should send a notification after X Seconds or when the App check for Updates.

I tried to work with these code examples but:

- [Pushing notifications when app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906371/pushing-notifications-when-app-is-closed) - too many Activities/doesn't work
- [How do I get my app to send a notification when it is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002188/how-do-i-get-my-app-to-send-a-notification-when-it-is-closed) - much information, but I don't know how to deal with it
- [How to send local notification android when app is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327453/how-to-send-local-notification-android-when-app-is-closed) - much information, but I don't know how to deal with it

If you can, try to explain it at an example, because beginners (like me) can easier learn it this way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this service all you need to do is Start this service onStop() in your activity lifecycle. With this code:
 `startService(new Intent(this, NotificationService.class));` 
then you can create a new Java Class and paste this code in it:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    String TAG = "Timers";
    int Your_X_SECS = 5;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        startTimer();

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        stoptimertask();
        super.onDestroy();


    }

    //we are going to use a handler to be able to run in our TimerTask
    final Handler handler = new Handler();


    public void startTimer() {
        //set a new Timer
        timer = new Timer();

        //initialize the TimerTask's job
        initializeTimerTask();

        //schedule the timer, after the first 5000ms the TimerTask will run every 10000ms
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, Your_X_SECS * 1000); //
        //timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000,1000); //
    }

    public void stoptimertask() {
        //stop the timer, if it's not already null
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    public void initializeTimerTask() {

        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        //TODO CALL NOTIFICATION FUNC
                        YOURNOTIFICATIONFUNCTION();

                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

After this you only need to combine the service with the manifest.xml:

```
<service
            android:name=".NotificationService"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="your.app.domain.NotificationService" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested your code for my App and it works!

Comment: According to [this article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks), "TimerTask - Doesn't run in UIThread and is not reliable. Consensus is to never use [TimerTask](http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/)."  Nikhil Gupta's answer is better.

Answer (score 8):

You can use alarm manager to do this [Not tested on latest Android versions and releases and is a pretty old answer].
Follow below steps :

1. Use alarmmanager to create an alarm of after X seconds.

   Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
   intent.putExtra("NotificationText", "some text");
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ledgerId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 'X seconds in milliseconds', pendingIntent);
2. Use a AlarmBroadCast receiver in your app.

Declare in manifest file :

```
<receiver android:name=".utils.AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

3. In the broadcast receiver's on receive, you can create the notification.

   public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   ```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // create notification here
    }
   ```

   }

Comment: Thank you for your answer too. I tried it with your code and it already works. I decided to use the code from @Vaibhav Kadam because it is for my personally usings more attractive.

Comment: This seems to be more the preferred approach.  https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services#using-with-alarmmanager-for-periodic-tasks gives a more detailed description.

Comment: I don't think this works anymore as of 2021 Alarm Manager will not run when App is closed

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer from [Nikhil Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4792879/nikhil-gupta) and referring to the website provided by [Bondolin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1399272/bondolin) in the comments, adding the attribute `android:process=":remote"` to the `receiver` allowed me to post a notification even when the app is completely closed.

```
<receiver
    android:name = ".utils.AlarmReceiver"
    android:process=":remote" >  <!-- this line is important -->
</receiver>
```

And the rest of the code is basically the same. An important thing to note is that the class `AlarmReceiver` should not contain any reference to the `MainActivity`, since when the app is closed, the `MainActivity` class is not instantiated. `NullPointerException` will be thrown if you attempt to reference `MainActivity` in the `AlarmReceiver` class when the app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check active apps using service and display notification if activity is not running.