# How to create notification after android app is swiped out of memory?

Tags: android, push-notification

```
 @Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    int DELAY=4000;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            create_notification();

        }
    },DELAY);
```

It creates a notification while the app is still in memory. Swiping the app off the memory does not create notification. I am looking for a method which is called when the app is killed.
Here I am trying to create dummy notification with the app itself. i do not wish to use services like FCM

Comment: call this in onDestroy()

Comment: Should I call my notification before or after super.onDestroy()

Comment: I think before super()

Comment: I tried but did not work

Comment: try printing logs, if your method is getting called or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send a notification when the app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674850/send-a-notification-when-the-app-is-closed)