# How To Run A Code or Full App on Background

Tags: java, android, runnable, foreground-service

my App get a Notification when i get time  Like Alarm i Just want to Run my app on Background to Can Push my Notification when time come

i was Try to Search about that Problem and ask on Many Android Groups and i Use then a Thread but Nothing work

```
   if (level==100){

    Thread T1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
  // PushNotification Method
                     PushNotification();

        }
    });
    T1.start();
        }
```

The Code only Run when App Open but When Close the App the Code Not work

Comment: Background service below **Oreo**, Foreground service >= **Oreo**

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to receive notifications from GCM, then create a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` that can be used to receive the notification and handle it appropriately.

On the other hand, if you're trying to send a normal notification from within your app, then create your own background `Service` that can be used to send the notification. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674850/send-a-notification-when-the-app-is-closed) to a similar [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39675175/11016588) that you can use for reference.

Comment: Nope i Not Use Any Clouding to use that

Comment: I've updated my answer, mark as correct if it answers your question (or add a comment if you have any more doubts). Cheers.

Comment: Nope Nothing Help too