# Send notifications when the foreground timer stops

Tags: java, android-studio, notifications, android-notifications, countdowntimer

I have some troubles with creating a way to send notifications foreground when the timer hits 00:00.

I mean, i want that when the timer ends, it sends a notification event if the app is closed.

I already found a way to show notifications and to make a timer who works even if the app is closed.

But when i put the function to send notification at the end of the timer it only works when the app is opened.

There is my MainActivity.java

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);


        mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.timerTv);
        mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.btn_start_pause);
        mButtonReset =  findViewById(R.id.btn_reset);



        mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mTimerRunning) {
                    pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    startTimer();
                }


            }
        });
        mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });


    }







    private void startTimer() {
        mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimeLeftInMillis=0;
                updateCountDownText();
                mTimerRunning = false;
                updateButtons();


                Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_1_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_money)
                        .setContentTitle("Test 1")
                        .setContentText("Important Message")
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                        .build();
                notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

            }
        }.start();
        mTimerRunning = true;
        updateButtons();
    }
    private void pauseTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
        updateButtons();
    }
    private void resetTimer() {
        mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateCountDownText();
        updateButtons();
    }
    private void updateCountDownText() {
        int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }
    private void updateButtons() {
        if (mTimerRunning) {
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Pause");
        } else {
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 1000) {
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < START_TIME_IN_MILLIS) {
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
        editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
        editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
        editor.apply();
        if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
        mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);
        updateCountDownText();
        updateButtons();
        if (mTimerRunning) {
            mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
            mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
                mTimerRunning = false;
                updateCountDownText();
                updateButtons();
            } else {
                startTimer();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

App Java Class

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static final String CHANNEL_1_ID = "channel1";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        createNotificationChannels();
    }
    private void createNotificationChannels() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_1_ID,
                    "Channel 1",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.krisix.notificationtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />


    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <service android:name=".ExampleService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you for your help !

Have a nice day

Krisix

Comment: somewhere in your onStop method, you should check if the timer is done, and if it is. and the application is stopped, you can launch the notifcation, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674850/send-a-notification-when-the-app-is-closed

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help sorry i'm a beginner so i'm not sure i understand all the things you told me.
So do you mean something like this ?

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);


        mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.timerTv);
        mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.btn_start_pause);
        mButtonReset =  findViewById(R.id.btn_reset);



        mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mTimerRunning) {
                    pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    startTimer();
                }


            }
        });
        mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });


    }


    private void startTimer() {
        mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimeLeftInMillis=0;
                updateCountDownText();
                mTimerRunning = false;
                updateButtons();

                if(mTimeLeftInMillis==0){
                    callNotification();
                }

            }
        }.start();
        mTimerRunning = true;
        updateButtons();
    }
    private void pauseTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
        updateButtons();
    }
    private void resetTimer() {
        mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateCountDownText();
        updateButtons();
    }
    private void updateCountDownText() {
        int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }
    private void updateButtons() {
        if (mTimerRunning) {
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Pause");
        } else {
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 1000) {
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < START_TIME_IN_MILLIS) {
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
        editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
        editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
        editor.apply();
        if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }



    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
        mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);
        updateCountDownText();
        updateButtons();
        if (mTimerRunning) {
            mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
            mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
                mTimerRunning = false;
                updateCountDownText();
                updateButtons();
            } else {
                startTimer();
            }
        }
    }

    public void callNotification(){
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_1_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_money)
                .setContentTitle("Test 1")
                .setContentText("Important Message")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .build();
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }

}
```