# Android Studio push notifications when app is closed

Tags: java, android, push-notification, background-process

How would I make an app to send a notification if it’s closed?
I’m making an app that reads the data from the web server and I need to send the notification to the user only if the app is closed and the value on the web server is changed.

Comment: I'm sure you can find a lot of examples online. What have you tried and where are you stuck even after searching online? Post the logcat if you're getting any errors.

Comment: Couldn’t find what I was looking for because all I can find are timed notifications and on-button click ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674850/send-a-notification-when-the-app-is-closed.

Comment: If the payload only contains a data block and not a notification block, your app will be created and your fcm service will receive the payload and then you can do whatever you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been struggling with this for a while, and finally I had to use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Sorry for answering late, but I implemented FCM into my app, and now my question is how would I automatically send a notification to a user if the variable on the webserver has changed and when the app is not opened.

Comment: FCM is sent from server. You can implement a listener on your web server, if the variable changes then send the FCM notification. I did this with a go-lang webserver integrated FCM.

Comment: Ok, but I don’t want to send a notification every time the state changes, I want to send the notification only if the app is closed.